# Best way to select discrete values jquery widget

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am on a project where the user specifies a schedule for different medicines. Lets say a patient is being given a chemotherapy and he needs to intake some drugs. The therapy is of 4 cycles, each cycle lasting for 30 days.

Now I need the user to be able to select the nth days in those 30 days when the patient needs to take his/her medicine.

Right now for this case, I am just laying out 30 checkboxes and the user selects the nth days.

I thought of using multiselect, but I am really short of space, as the form is a bit complicated. I need to accomodate this discrete day selector either horizontally, or implement something like datepicker, but not with specific dates.

Does anybody knows any jquery plugins to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery UI Button Buttonset http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox
very close to what I needed.

I already had 30 checkboxes, and was already using jQuery UI
I just needed to add this one line

```
$('.med-schedule').buttonset();
```

And fix some css :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JQuery UI Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid)?

Looks like this can solve your problem.

There is DEMO on the link, with the interface you want.

(For multiple choice click with CTRL button pressed)